# qt runtime error, The program has unexpectedly finished

Tags: c++, macos, qt

This is a class project I'm working on, and we are using bitbucket. I'm the only one who is using mac for running Qt. everyone else is using windows or linux. For some reason my mac doesn't run the program, but it works on theirs. Qt Creator 3.5.0 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.5.0 (Clang 6.0 (Apple), 64 bit)
I've been spending days, but no one could figure it out.

Starting /Users/SepehrRaissian/cs1c-project-1/build-Warehouse-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_clang_64bit-Debug/Warehouse.app/Contents/MacOS/Warehouse...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/Users/SepehrRaissian/cs1c-project-1/build-Warehouse-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_clang_64bit-Debug/Warehouse.app/Contents/MacOS/Warehouse crashed

Comment: do you have environment set to qt binaries?

Comment: could you elaborate on that ?

Comment: Can you run it from Qt Creator? I see that you starting it using binary. Can you launch `Warehouse.app` bundle from `Finder`?

Comment: You need to provide the error message if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to change my working directory in run settings.